# Why does the lambda "var a: ()->Int = {()->5};" give the error "Expected no parameters"?

Tags: function, kotlin, lambda, parameters

Why is this not correct:

```
var a: ()->Int = {()->5};
```

and this is:

```
var a: ()->Int = {5};
```

For the first one I get an error in Android studio: Expected no parameters.
I don't understand why, as I have empty brackets. I did similar thing in Android studio and the error was that `()->Unit` is expected as I parameter to a function, but it received `(Any?)->Unit`, although I sent `()->Unit`.

Answer (score 1):

So whats going on here? Lets break it down in two things, its type and its implementation

```
var a: () -> Int
```

This tells us the variable a is of the type "function that takes no parameters and returns an Int"

Now some implementations that fits our type. A named function could look like

```
fun randomInt(): Int = (0..10).random()

a = ::randomInt
```

This will work because randomInt is a function that takes no parameter and gives back an Int.

Lets do an anonymous function,

```
a = fun(): Int { return (0..10).random() }
```

This will also work because our anonymous function takes no parameter and gives back an Int.

And finally a lambda.

```
a = { () -> (0..10).random() }
```

This wont work!? Yeah.. named and anonymous functions do use an empty () for parameters and it should always be there. lambdas without parameters actually doesn't, they just have nothing as a parameter list.

```
a = { -> (0..10).random() }
```

But we can also omit the arrow if we dont have any arguments.

```
a = { (0..10).random() }
```

tldr: () is only used when defining the type of a function with no parameters, its not used in lambda expressions that create that function.

Comment: you can do `someFunction(::functionWithMatchingType)` or a lambda like `someFunction({returnValue})` but as the last parameter is a lambda you can have it outside of the parenthesis `someFunction() {returnValue}` and now the parenthesis is empty so it can be omitted `someFunction {returnValue}`

Comment: @gidds thanks! I just started learning kotlin and should probably read the docs.

Comment: As, indeed, should I!  I'll post a revised version of my comment _without_ the egregious mistakes…

Comment: Good answer, but one nitpick: in Kotlin, [anonymous function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#anonymous-functions) is not a synonym for lambda, but an expression like `fun(…): ReturnType { ... }` or `fun(…) = ...`.